# MS Access - Save Filename and Filepath to Fields in a Table

Tags: database, ms-access, vba, filenames, filepath

I am trying to save a selected file name and file path into fields in table. I am using a form and inserting a button and applying some code I found online to get the filename and path into a msgbox.

```
Private Sub Command0_Click()

    Dim f As Object
    Dim strFile As String
    Dim strFolder As String
    Dim varItem As Variant

    Set f = Application.FileDialog(3)
    f.AllowMultiSelect = True
    If f.Show Then
        For Each varItem In f.SelectedItems
            strFile = Dir(varItem)
            strFolder = Left(varItem, Len(varItem) - Len(strFile))
            MsgBox "Folder: " & strFolder & vbCrLf & _
                "File: " & strFile
        Next
    End If
    Set f = Nothing

End Sub
```

Could anybody please help me and explain how I now get the resulting data from the the message box into the fields in my table (The field destinations are called "`ImageFilePath`" & "`ImageFileName`").

Thanks Guys

Comment: Thsi is basic ms-access database work - look up examples for adding new records and try something out. This is not relevant code you'e sharing

Answer (score 0):

Here's a tweaked snippet.  Add the items to the recordset of a related table to store the full file name/path with the foreign key.  I move all mine using the `Save AS` to a folder.

```
dim obj as object
dim rsimg as dao.recordset
Set obj = CreateObject("WScript.shell")
Set rsimg = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tbltostorefilenameswforeignkey", dbOpenDynaset)
Set fdialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
With fdialog
    .AllowMultiSelect = True
    .Title = "Select Images To Add - Multiples OK"
    .InitialFileName = obj.specialfolders("desktop")
    .InitialView = msoFileDialogViewLargeIcons
    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add "Images", "*.jpg,*.gif,*.png"
    If .Show = True Then
        For Each varfile In .SelectedItems
        Name varfile As Currentproject.path & "\yourfilefoldername" & "\" &  Right(varfile, Len(varfile) - InStrRev(varfile, "\"))
       rsimg.AddNew
       rsimg("ItemId") = Me.ID
       rsimg("filepath") = Currentproject.path & "\yourfilefoldername" & "\" & Right(varfile, Len(varfile) - InStrRev(varfile, "\"))
       rsimg.Update
       Next varfile
   End If
End With
```

If you are only using one file for each record and want to save them in the table then set `.allowmultiselect = false`, remove the `for each next` loop, and in place of `varfile` just use `.selecteditems.item(1)`

As you got it,

```
dim itm as string
itm = f.selecteditems.item(1)
me.imagefilename = dir(itm)
```

and the same for the folder path

Answer (score 0):

I used your code and after the msgBox line I added (Me."`FieldName` you want to save the path to". `value = strFolder & strFile`), it saved the whole path to my field after it showed the info on the `msgBox`